# My header won't be responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, bootstrap-4

I have a header in my website designed in bootstrap and HTML, it is a sticky header, the image is supposed to appear above the menu nav and  I was trying to make it responsive, I got it to reduce in size but the image does not center to the middle of the page and menu comes off wrong when the page is resized too. Not really great with CSS.

below is the HTML code

```css
.align-center {
  background: transparent;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.align-center a {
  color: #70726F;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.align-center a:hover {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20% !important;
  z-index: 100;
  left: 100px;
  font-weight: bold;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.menu-header a:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-header .active {
  color: darkcyan;
}

.center-image {
  position: relative;
  left: 255px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.cart-image {
  right: 30px;
}

#logo_wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<head>
  <title>Home | Relationinc</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
  <link href="https://relationinc.com.ng/lib/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://relationinc.com.ng/lib/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body id="home" class="theme">
  <header class="header">
    <div class="wrapper">

      <div id="logo_wrapper">
        <a class="center-image align-center image" href="index.html" title="Relationinc">
          <img alt="Relationinc" src="https://relationinc.com.ng/new images/logo-text.jpeg">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="cart-link cart-image">
        <a href="cart.html" title="Cart">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 30 30">
              <path d="M22.7 8c-.9-3.4-4-6-7.7-6S8.2 4.6 7.3 8H2l3 20h20l3-20h-5.3zM15 4c2.6 0 4.8 1.7 5.6 4H9.3c.9-2.3 3.1-4 5.7-4zm8.3 22H6.7L4.3 10H7v3h2v-3h12v3h2v-3h2.7l-2.4 16z" />
            </svg>
          <i id="cartcount" class="him-counts hide">0</i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="align-center menu-header">
      <div class="container text-center">
        <a href="index.html" class="active">
          Home
        </a>
        <a href="categories.html">
          Collections
        </a>
        <a href="aboutus.html">
          About Us
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>

</body>
```

Comment: The reason is quite simple: You are using too much custom css instead of letting Bootstrap do the job it was designed to do. In other words, why aren't you using Bootstrap classes to get the job done?

Comment: I did not really know how to get bootstrap to achieve what you can see am trying to do. So I started building my own classes.

Comment: And is there a reason you aren't using the Bootstrap navbar for the menu?

Answer (score 0):

Replace Your this code I hope this will help you.

```
.center-image {
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: It now centers when the browser is reduced.but when the browser is in full size. it strays a bit to the left side.

Answer (score 0):

First, you are using bootstrap3 and bootstrap4 css both...why this?

be specific about the bootstrap version which one you want to use..

Use `img-responsive center-block` **bootstrap3** classes to your image...

or use `d-block mx-auto` to your image if you are using **bootstrap4**.

And also remove the `left:100px` from the header...I have changes some of your css.

If you want to make layout responsive be sure not to use fixed `px` values..try to use values in `%` if required anywhere.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.align-center {
  background: transparent;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

.align-center a {
  color: #70726F;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all .5s ease;
}

.align-center a:hover {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20% !important;
  z-index: 100;
  font-weight: bold;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.menu-header a:hover {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-header .active {
  color: darkcyan;
}

.cart-image {
  right: 30px;
}

#logo_wrapper img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Zug+QiDoJOrZ5t4lssLdxGhVrurbmBWopoEl+M6BdEfwnCJZtKxi1KgxUyJq13dy" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-a5N7Y/aK3qNeh15eJKGWxsqtnX/wWdSZSKp+81YjTmS15nvnvxKHuzaWwXHDli+4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<body id="home" class="theme">
  <header class="header">
    <div class="wrapper">

      <div id="logo_wrapper">
        <a class="align-center image" href="index.html" title="Relationinc">
          <img alt="Relationinc" src="https://relationinc.com.ng/new images/logo-text.jpeg" class="img-responsive center-block">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="cart-link cart-image">
        <a href="cart.html" title="Cart">
          <svg viewBox="0 0 30 30">
              <path d="M22.7 8c-.9-3.4-4-6-7.7-6S8.2 4.6 7.3 8H2l3 20h20l3-20h-5.3zM15 4c2.6 0 4.8 1.7 5.6 4H9.3c.9-2.3 3.1-4 5.7-4zm8.3 22H6.7L4.3 10H7v3h2v-3h12v3h2v-3h2.7l-2.4 16z" />
            </svg>
          <i id="cartcount" class="him-counts hide">0</i>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="align-center menu-header">
      <div class="container text-center">
        <a href="index.html" class="active">
          Home
        </a>
        <a href="categories.html">
          Collections
        </a>
        <a href="aboutus.html">
          About Us
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```